# Java database error

Tags: java, mysql

I am using the following code to update a record in my database.

```
import java.sql.* ;

class JDBCUpdate
{
 public static void main( String args[] )
 {
       String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase";
  try
     {

      Class.forName( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" ) ;



   //  Database credentials
    String USER = "user";
    String PASS = "pass";

      // Get a connection to the database
       Connection  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);


      // Print all warnings
      for( SQLWarning warn = conn.getWarnings(); warn != null; warn = warn.getNextWarning() )
         {
          System.out.println( "SQL Warning:" ) ;
          System.out.println( "State  : " + warn.getSQLState()  ) ;
          System.out.println( "Message: " + warn.getMessage()   ) ;
          System.out.println( "Error  : " + warn.getErrorCode() ) ;
         }

      // Get a statement from the connection
      Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;

      // Execute the Update
      int rows = stmt.executeUpdate( "UPDATE people SET id = 9842 WHERE birthyear=3434" ) ;

      // Print how many rows were modified
      System.out.println( rows + " Rows modified" ) ;

      // Close the statement and the connection
      stmt.close() ;
      conn.close() ;
     }
  catch( SQLException se )
     {
      System.out.println( "SQL Exception:" ) ;

      // Loop through the SQL Exceptions
      while( se != null )
         {
          System.out.println( "State  : " + se.getSQLState()  ) ;
          System.out.println( "Message: " + se.getMessage()   ) ;
          System.out.println( "Error  : " + se.getErrorCode() ) ;

          se = se.getNextException() ;
         }
     }
  catch( Exception e )
     {
      System.out.println( e ) ;
     }
 }
}
```

In stmt.executeUpdate() if i try to update a record with text or any value other than integer an error is thrown. Can someone tell me how to overcome this error.

Comment: Please show your table definition.

Answer (score 0):

> In stmt.executeUpdate() if i try to update a record with text or any
>   value other than integer an error is thrown. Can someone tell me how
>   to overcome this error.

Now, look at your UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE people SET id = 9842 WHERE birthyear=3434
```

I bet is because the `Id` column is an integer and hence setting text in an integer field throws the exception.

Comment: No. I tried changing the name column with the following       (UPDATE people SET id = 9842 WHERE name=fhbb)

Comment: Ah, then that's because fhbb needs to be in single quotes as so: `UPDATE people SET id = 9842 WHERE name='fhbb' `